# Did I use all possible ways of talking about likeliness or unlikliness in English?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've tried to explore various ways of saying the same thing in English. Do they seem correct to you? Is anything missing?

1.1. He may know her phone number.
1.2. He might know her phone number.
1.3. Maybe he knows her phone number.
1.4. Perhaps he knows her phone number.

2.1. He must know her phone number.
2.2. He’s likely to know her phone number.
2.3. He probably knows her phone number.
2.4. It is likely that he knows her phone number.
2.5. He will know her phone number. (?)

3.1. He’ll probably learn her phone number.
3.2. He’s likely to learn her phone number.
3.3. It is likely that he'll learn her phone number.

4.1. He probably doesn’t know her phone number.
4.2. He’s not likely to know her phone number.
4.3. It is not likely that he knows her phone number.

5.1. He's not likely to learn her phone number.
5.2. He’ll probably not learn her phone number.
5.3. It is not likely that he'll learn her phone number.

6.1. He must've known her phone number.
6.2. He'll have known her phone number. (?)
6.3. He probably knew her phone number.
6.4. He is likely to have known her phone number.

Comment: There are innumerable ways to state something in English. While all sentences shown are used colloquially in English, to some extent, there are certainly **many** other ways to make that assertion, e.g., "Of course, he knows her number."

Answer (score 1):

In music (at least Western music), there are only 12 notes. But I don't think anyone can say that we have already used all possible ways of combining them to create songs.

Language is similar, although there are many more than 12 words available to express ourselves. I don't think you can definitively say that you have ever used **all possible ways** of talking about a concept. Your list shows a few examples, but you can create many more examples through creative combinations of the different words that are available to you in the English language.

On the examples you flagged with a question mark:

- 2.5 is correct, but it's out of place with the other examples because it indicates absolute certainty, while the other examples indicate
  uncertainty.
- In 6.1, I would use **must have** and not "must've".
- 6.2 is technically correct, but probably not used very often.